# AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: django, heroku, django-channels

При запуске `py manage.py runserver` все работает без ошибок.
Возникла потребность протестировать на сервере `heroku`.
При загрузке на `heroku` возникает `Application error`.

В `heroku logs` появляется ошибка:

```
    2021-10-13T07:44:14.143374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `daphne Quiz.asgi:application --port 22236
 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2`
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405529+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405551+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405640+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405651+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line
170, in entrypoint
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405777+00:00 app[web.1]: cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405779+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line
232, in run
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405911+00:00 app[web.1]: application = import_by_path(args.application)
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405911+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", lin
e 12, in import_by_path
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405982+00:00 app[web.1]: target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
2021-10-13T07:44:16.405992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, i
n import_module
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406091+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406200+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406262+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406325+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406387+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_remove
d
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406527+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./Quiz/asgi.py", line 9, in <module>
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406642+00:00 app[web.1]: from quiz_app.routing import ws_urlpatterns
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406642+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./quiz_app/routing.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406724+00:00 app[web.1]: from .consumers import PlayersConsumer
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406724+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./quiz_app/consumers.py", line 9, in <module>
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406785+00:00 app[web.1]: from .models import Player, Game
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406787+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/./quiz_app/models.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406853+00:00 app[web.1]: User = get_user_model()
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406863+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/_
_init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406973+00:00 app[web.1]: return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
2021-10-13T07:44:16.406981+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.
py", line 201, in get_model
2021-10-13T07:44:16.407101+00:00 app[web.1]: self.check_apps_ready()
2021-10-13T07:44:16.407109+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.
py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
2021-10-13T07:44:16.407215+00:00 app[web.1]: raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
2021-10-13T07:44:16.407257+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
2021-10-13T07:44:16.641612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-13T07:44:16.777535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-13T07:44:16.859199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-13T07:44:17.346824+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bemaximal
quiz.herokuapp.com request_id=ac617cb3-c39e-4822-a9ac-f5fd589092d1 fwd="178.125.141.61" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes= protocol=http
```

При запуске `django-admin check`:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\Quiz\venv\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_ar
gv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\check.py", line 63, in ha
ndle
    self.check(
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\translation.py", line 60, in check_lan
guage_settings_consistent
    get_supported_language_variant(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\1\pycharmprojects\quiz\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LANGUAGE_CODE, but settings are not configured. You must
either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

**Файл asgi.py:**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from quiz_app.routing import ws_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Quiz.settings')
django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            ws_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**Файл settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for Quiz project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os

import dj_database_url

from django.conf import settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_app',
    'quiz_app',
    'channels'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Quiz.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Quiz.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'Quiz.asgi.application'

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
prod_db = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)

# Channel_layers

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо)

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки?

Comment: Я обновил текст ошибки, теперь полный...

Comment: Текст ошибки намекает, что вы забыли прописать переменную окружения `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` https://newbedev.com/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-settings-module-or-call-settings-configure-before-accessing-settings

Comment: Тем не менее при вызове heroku config в поле DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: Quiz.settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в импорте. Изменил **asgi.py** следующим образом:

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Quiz.settings')
django.setup()
from quiz_app.routing import ws_urlpatterns
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            ws_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).